# How to initialize in the main class an Array field from a constructor in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, constructor

Sorry if this is a silly question or if I don't put it correctly but I'll try my best to explain what the problem is.

I am supposed to create a book Class that stores the name of a book, the ISBN, the price and the author's name. Since a book may have more than one author I'm supposed to create an Array or ArrayList for this field. Everything seems to be working fine but when I initialize the Array field as a String the IDE displays an error. Am I missing something here? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
public class Books {
private String bookName;
private String ISBN;
private int price;
private String [] authorsList;

public Books (String bookName, String ISBN, int price, String[] authorsList){
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
    this.price = price;
    this.authorsList = authorsList;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Book title: " + bookName +
           "\nISBN: " + ISBN + 
           "\nPrice: " + price +
           "\nAuthor: " + authorsList;  
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {          

    Books book1 = new Books("Harry Potter","12345",10,"J. K. Rowling");

    System.out.println(book1.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: You should post the error so we can see what's wrong :)

Comment: you are passing a `String` intead of `String[]`

Comment: `, new String[]{"J. K. Rowling"})`

Comment: A `String` is not an array.  If you need an array, then make one, for instance with `new String[] {"J. K. Rowling" }`.  Alternatively, if the parameter in question is the last one, then you can declare it as a varargs parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write System.out.println like that you can see inside of array

```
  System.out.println(book1.bookName + "\n" + book1.ISBN+"\n" + book1.price+"\n" +  Arrays.toString(authorsList));
```

You can't see it now because it's an array and if you write `System.out.println(book1.toString());` this way java shows only its location.That's why you saw something like this [Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55

or please change your toString method to this now it is showed
**Actually this way is better:**

```
public String toString(){
    return "Book title: " + bookName +
           "\nISBN: " + ISBN + 
           "\nPrice: " + price +
           "\nAuthor: " + Arrays.toString(authorsList);  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {          
    Books book1 = new Books("Harry Potter","12345", 10, new String[]{"J. K. Rowling"});
    System.out.println(book1.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to initialize your array:

```
new String[]{"J. K. Rowling"};
```

You're passing a String in the constructor instead of an Array.

Comment: Thank you!

It does solve the error but now instead of having the text displayed I get something else:

Book title: Harry Potter
ISBN: 12345
Price: 10
Author: [Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55

Am I doing something wrong with the array?

Comment: Think of the Array as a bookcase and the content are Strings. Display the string and you'll get what you want. When you try to display the bookcase you get weird stuff. Display the book inside :)